# How to define the order status after creating an shipping?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have searched a lot with google but somehow I'm using the wrong search terms or there is no answer to my specific problem yet.

In Magento I'd like to have the following procedure: Customer creates an order, I generate an invoice (Status switches to processing) which is fine. I create shipment against the order ( Status swiches to Complete) I don't want it to switch to complete, so I created a - New Status ( Cust_ Confirmation ) Now the order stays in Cust_Confirmation State. How do it mark it complete?
This is what i want: Pending-->Processing-->Cust_ Confirmation-->Complete
I am stuck now between Cust_Confirmation & Complete

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to follow this link to make custom order status and use it without any problems:

http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-order-state/